# Makefile target requires dependency of other target

Tags: c, makefile, linker

I have three c files and their header files:

1. main/program.{c,h}
2. lib/lib1.{c,h}
3. lib/lib2.{c,h}

`program` depends on `lib1.o`, which depends on `lib2.o`. `program` does not directly depend on `lib2.o`.

`program.main()` calls `lib1.func1()`, which calls `lib2.func2()`.

I have two `Makefile`s; one in the main folder, and another in lib.

**lib/Makefile:**

```
all: lib1.o lib2.o

lib1.o: lib2.o lib2.h lib1.h

lib2.o: lib2.h
```

**main/Makefile:**

```
VPATH=../lib

all: program

program: program.o lib1.o lib1.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

When I run `make -C main all`, I get an `undefined reference to 'func2'` error. Both the `lib` object files compiled fine.

Do I need to make `lib2` a dependency of `program` even though it doesn't directly call it?

Comment: Object files are standalone translation units, you need to list all object files needed for the `program` target.

Comment: So I need to include lib2.o as a dependency of program?

Comment: Where are the recipes? Are those makefiles just snippets or are they complete?

Comment: Good spot; corrected. lib/Makefiles has no explicit recipes, only main/Makefile

Comment: And what recipe makes lib1.o and lib2.o ?

Comment: It's made automatically by make because it understands to look for a corresponding .c file

Comment: Ok, I did not know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  lib1.o contains a reference to a function that only exists in lib2.o.  If you don't tell the linker for main to also link against lib2.o it will never find it.  The compiler doesn't resolves the reference from lib1 to lib2 at compile time, it just checks the header to make sure it is being called correctly.

You could have you lib directory Makefile build a .a (man ar) which includes both .o files, then link against the .a file from your main build.

Comment: I see. So do I actually need to list lib2.o as a dependency for lib1.o?

Comment: Yes.  You do.  Or build a lib.a file containing both .o files.